I want to check user has nitro
It returns None even though the user has nitro
@bot.command(name="nitro")
async def has_nitro(ctx, user_id: int):
    user = await ctx.guild.fetch_member(user_id)
    if user:
        nitro_status = 'Yes' if user.premium_since else 'No'
        await ctx.send(f"{user.name} has nitro: {nitro_status}")
    else:
        await ctx.send("User not found in this server.")


The premium_since attribute is for "when the member used their “Nitro boost” on the guild".

This question is similar to: How to check if a user has discord nitro using a bot. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

discord.py does not expose this information because the Discord API does not really expose it. There is a documented premium_type field on the User object, but it requires the identity OAuth scope. In practice, this means you cannot get this information from a typical bot. You'd need to build an application that authenticates with Discord via OAuth2, and users would explicitly need to grant your application permissions to access information on their behalf.
According to this discussion, Discord currently has no plans to remove the identity scope requirement.
